# ListView don't remember SelectedItems

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a `ListView` with `SelectionMode="Multiple"`, if I change page and then I navigate back to the page with the `ListView`, there is no selected items, every items appear deselected.

I have tried to extend the ListView, this is my code:

```
    public class MultiSelectionListView : ListView
    {
        protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
        {
            var myModel = item as MyModel;

            var lvElement = element as ListViewItem;
            lvElement.IsSelected = myModel.IsSelected;

            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(lvElement, item);
        }
    }
```

This is my list view

```
<Controls:MyListView SelectionMode="Multiple"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListViewItemStyle}" />
```

But even doing this it doesn't work.

I Am quite sure that i'm doing something wrong, but i don't understand what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the page's `NavigationCacheMode` property to `Required` .. that'll cache your text input, list selected items etc.. :)

Read more about it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode